# Ruby on Rails Logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations

I know the title might be ambiguous but I was unsure what heading it would come under. I am not sure if there is a "best practice" on this so here it goes...

I have a basic social network application I am building from scratch. Users can post a status and people can comment on that status, people should also be able to comment on a comment. I think I understand how it should work but wouldn't mind someone else giving me their point of view. So (association-wise) a status has_many comments and in turn a comment has just one status. Comments have_many subcomments and subcomments belong to just one comment. How do these nested comments work?

If a user posts a status and another user posts a comment; that's fine. However, if.... user 1 posts a status and user 2 comments on that status, user 3 then comments on user 2's comment (so user 1 has created a status, user 2 a comment and user 3 a subcomment) what happens when user 2 replies to user 3's subcomment? is it still classes as a subcomment (ie.. a comment on a comment) or would it have to be nested even further like so:

User 1 creates a status, user 2 creates a comment, user 3 creates a subcomment, user 2 creates a subsubcomment

That doesn't seem like the correct way to do it as it would eventually get too messy if users were replying to eachothers comments on the same status.

Update: Looking into associations another possibility would be that a status has_many comments and a comment has_many replies. But that doesn't solve my problem... what if a user replys to another users reply on a comment? a status has_many comments, a comment has_many replies.... but a reply also has_many replies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[#262 Trees with Ancestry - RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) - describes using gem for building nested messages.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I always use **[awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set)** gem for such cases. You will only need one model for all comments. More about nested sets and their usage in general you can read on **[wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)**(It has really simple logic). For ready to use solutions check **[acts_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading)** gem's page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would upvote it but I can't at the moment because my account is too new. Although I marked Ihar's answer as my official answer (his answer relates more to what I have been looking at.. ie Ancestry) your references are very helpful (especially the ready to use solution so I can get a better understanding of it working in practice) Thank you for the help.